# How do I get all the properties and methods of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

I can get all the properties and methods of a DOM element in the following way

```
var e = document.createElement('div')
let arr = []
for(let key in e){
  arr.push(key)
  console.log(key)
  //cloneNode
  //...
}
```

But I want to know why the following methods are not available?

```
const arr = Object.key(e)
//result: []

const arr2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)
//result: []
```

**why?**

Assuming that：

**How do I get all the properties and methods of a DOM element and store them in an array**

Comment: `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` basically work the same - they only give you the own keys (the former excludes non-enumerable ones, the latter includes them). In either case `cloneNode` and the rest are not *own* keys - they come from the prototype chain.

Comment: "*How do I get all the properties and methods of a DOM element and store them in an array*" Like you did in the first snippet? You could also walk up the prototype chain and collect all keys into a single list but feels like more work than the loop.

Comment: @VLAZ wow,I see. Can you answer this question? I want more people to see it

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao VLAZ's answer was precisely right. I built on that same principle in my solution, which shows the logic to set up a recursive function to retrieve all available properties and methods from the prototype chain, and to either store those key name in an array, or to store the key names and their values associated with the originally passed-in element in an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VLAZ mentioned, many of those properties you want to retrieve come from the prototype chain. In order to store all of them in an array, we will actually need to loop through the prototype chain using recursion.

Using recursion will allow us to create a simple function we can use to quickly retrieve all available properties and methods for any node or object without having to set up a `for..in` loop each time. Here is how I would achieve this:

```js
var e = document.createElement('div');

const getAllProperties = (e, props = []) => e.__proto__ ? getAllProperties(e.__proto__, props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e))) : [...new Set(props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)))];

const divProps = getAllProperties(e);

console.log(`ALL ${e.constructor.name} properties (${divProps.length})`, divProps);
```

You could even take this one step further and return each property and method available along with the values associated with keys by mapping them back to the original node/object in a new key-value object:

```js
const e = document.createElement('div');

const getAllProperties = (o, e = o, props = []) => e.__proto__ ? getAllProperties(o, e.__proto__, props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e))) : Object.fromEntries([...new Set(props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)))].map(prop => [prop, o[prop]]));

const divProps = getAllProperties(e);

console.log(`ALL ${e.constructor.name} properties (${Object.keys(divProps).length})`, divProps);
```

Comment: Wow, the ideal answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @BaiClassmateXiao! I thoroughly enjoyed putting this together as well. Let me know if you have any questions about my functions. I'm happy to explain further. I use `[…new Set()]` to remove any duplicates from the final array, and I use an additional parameter `o` in my second function to preserve the original element `e` as I loop recursively, whereas my first function overwrites the original parameter `e` every time it passes `e.__proto__` back into the function.

Comment: If you implement the first function that gives you all keys (which is easier), then the second one that gives you all keys and values (a bit harder) becomes absolutely trivial: `o => Object.fromEntries(getAllProperties(o).map(x => [x, o[x]]));` :P

Comment: @VLAZ I 100% agree, just showing it as an option, but it's clear to see even running the snippets above just how much slower it is. It's much quicker in a production environment, but never really suitable for use in a production project. More so just an internal option developers can use as a reference.

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao upon further research I discovered that the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method is more reliable and comprehensive than the `Object.keys()` method. For the sample element used, a div, `Object.keys()` returns 297 properties whereas `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns 310, inclusive of all 297 returned by `Object.keys()`. For array types `[]`, `Object.keys()` returns 0 properties, even recursively, whereas `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns 43. I have updated my solution to reflect this change.

Answer (score 2):

It is because these built-in properties of a DOM object are enumerable but are not own properties. In fact these properties are inherited properties. If a property is enumerable but not own-property [propertyIsEnumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) method will give `false`.

[image]

Observe the example below:

```js
let inp = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0]
console.log(inp.propertyIsEnumerable('onclick'))
```

```html
<input type='range' class='someclass' min='0' max='100' />
```

As the output of the above code snippet gives out `false`, that means the property `onclick` is enumerable but not an own property. Any enumerable properties appear in `for...in` loop. But only enumerable and own properties appear in `Object.keys` method. That is why you get the value in `for...in` loop but not with `Object.keys`

Comment: Very much you answer，But it does appear in `for in`,So I'm wondering if there's a way to get them

Comment: Object.keys gives own-enumerable properties. But `for..in` gives only enumerable properties. So, these build in properties are enumerable but not own properties. I am updating my answer

Comment: Perfect explanation

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you only need the keys and not their values.

First, confirm if the var e as you defined below is indeed an object.

```
var e = document.createElement('div')
```

Second, the correct method that returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would is below

```
Object.keys(e)
```

[MDN link for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

If you refer to the MDN docs you will find the below example

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I want are the properties and methods of DOM elements, such as `align, title, lang, translate, dir, hidden....`

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao thanks for clarifying. You can use the attribute.name property to pull out the HTML DOM property names. This will give you an array and then you can map over it to get all names of attributes. W3S link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_attr_name.asp